# We didn't create a branch for an enhancement that turned out much larger than expected

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I am looking for advice on the best remedy for our situation as well as ways to avoid doing this in the future, but mainly a the best course of action to remedy it. Obviously, I know that some of what follows is bad, in a perfect world it wouldn't happen.

6 months ago I began an enhancement that turned into more a project wide refactoring. As we were working, it became necessary to build from trunk for a client demanding nightly builds of code going into the project from elsewhere on the team, so this made it impossible to check work in.
Thus far, we've kept up to date, and the external changes have been very localized, so we don't yet have a merging nightmare on our hands.

We are approaching the date where we branch a release version from trunk and we'll be able to check in again, but in the meantime the other developers mentioned above are beginning to work on code that should be up to date with our code.

How should we go about making this code available to them? Here's the best solution I came up with:

1. Pull in all changes from trunk
2. Create an empty branch and check my working copy in to it
3. Developers begin working from this new refactor branch
4. Once the release version is branched, merge the refactoring branch back into trunk

The other option is to continue the work and check in once the release is branched, with possible more merging to be done by everyone.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: In short - is your task "merge refactored code with modified base?"